# creating a folder structure tree from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.date_range('01-01-2020','01-12-2020')
df = pd.DataFrame({'folder' : ['GB123', 'GB1234']*12, 'dates' :np.repeat(s,2)})
print(df.head(5))
   folder      dates
0   GB123 2020-01-01
1  GB1234 2020-01-01
2   GB123 2020-01-02
3  GB1234 2020-01-02
4   GB123 2020-01-03
```

with this dataframe, I've been attempting to create a file tree function, much like below to show the relationship of files and and sub folders to illustrate some blob storage architecture.

```
def tree(directory):
    print(f'+ {directory}')
    for path in sorted(directory.rglob('*')):
        depth = len(path.relative_to(directory).parts)
        spacer = '    ' * depth
        print(f'{spacer}+ {path.name}')

>>> tree(pathlib.Path.cwd())
+ /home/gahjelle/realpython
    + directory_1
        + file_a.md
    + directory_2
        + file_a.md
        + file_b.pdf
        + file_c.py
    + file_1.txt
    + file_2.txt
```

the furthest I've gotten is to groupby by the folder and iterate over it, but I can never get it quite right

```
for folder, date in df.groupby('folder'):
    print(f"-- {folder}\n\t--{date.dates}")
```

which gives me the below which isn't quite right.

```
-- GB123
    --0    2020-01-01
2    2020-01-02
4    2020-01-03
6    2020-01-04
8    2020-01-05
10   2020-01-06
12   2020-01-07
14   2020-01-08
16   2020-01-09
18   2020-01-10
20   2020-01-11
22   2020-01-12
```

i'm after something like :

```
--- GB123
            --|--- 01/01/2019
              |--- 02/01/2019
              |--- 03/01/2019
--- GB1234
            --|--- 01/01/2019
              |--- 02/01/2019
              |--- 03/01/2019
```

is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this close to what you're looking for?

```
for f in df.folder.unique():
    tdf = df[df.folder == f]
    print(f"-- {f}")
    for date in tdf.dates:
        print(f"\t--|{date}")
```

Output:

```
-- GB123
    --|2020-01-01 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-02 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-03 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-04 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-05 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-06 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-07 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-08 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-09 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-10 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-11 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-12 00:00:00
-- GB1234
    --|2020-01-01 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-02 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-03 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-04 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-05 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-06 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-07 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-08 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-09 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-10 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-11 00:00:00
    --|2020-01-12 00:00:00
```

Comment: perfect i tweaked the last line to `print(f"\t--|{date.strftime('%y%m%d'}")`

Comment: @Datanovice Awesome, glad it worked out for you. I'm not sure how well it could be adapted to deeper folder structures without a lot of hard coding though.

Comment: I went 4 levels deep by adapting your code, but I wonder if there is a one shot function that could handle n levels of folder structures.

Comment: That's what I was wondering too, I'm not aware of one though.